# Login defaults to the wrong domain in certain situations

Tags: authentication

User authentication fails in certain situations because the domain is incorrect. If my domain is DOMAINA the user would have to enter DOMAINA\username to authenticate correctly. When we designed our farm, our intention was for users within the network to auto authenticate. For the most part, this works. However there are occasions where the defaulted domain is the box name. When users try to authenticate from home, the domain is often incorrect. I wish I had more specifics in terms of a common thread among occurrences. All users are using IE7+. 
Is there a way to force the use of a domain when users authenticate from home? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option you can explore is using Basic Authentication in IIS. This will allow you to specify the default domain for users logging in. The risk here is that credentials are sent as plain text, so you'll need to make sure you're using a valid SSL cert on the site. I don't know what this would do to the internal users, I think they should still be able to auto-auth as needed.

Comment: Thanks David! I will try this in my test environment.  appreciate the information.